# Access to TRTTIField.FieldType within classes when the array type is created ad-hoc

Tags: delphi, rtti

I need to read all member variables of a class by using RTTI. I get for the field type nil if an array type is declared ad-hoc inside the class. If the same type is declared outside ( before) the class, reading the field type works as expected.

```
type 
  TMyClass = class
    MyArray: array[0..1] of double;
  end;

var
  MyClass: TMyClass;
  Ctx: TRTTIContext;
  T: TRTTIType;
  F: TRTTIField;
begin
  MyClass := TMyClass.Create;
  Ctx := TRTTIContext.Create;
  T := Ctx.GetType(MyClass.ClassInfo);
  for F in T.GetFields do
    case F.FieldType.TypeKind of // <-- AV because F.FieldType is nil in this situation
      tkFloat: ;
    end;
end;
```

`F.DataType` is also nil in this situation.

I don't see this issue if I declare the class like this:

```
type 
  TMyArr = array[0..1] of double;
  TMyClass = class
    MyArray: TMyArr;
  end;
```

If the array is declared as dynamic array (`myArray: array of double`) I don't see this problem.

Is there a workaround for this situation as I am developing a component where I do not write the declaration of the class myself?

I tested this code with Delphi 12 and 11.

Comment: This is expected behavior. In the first snippet, you are not declaring a distinct type for the array, so there is no RTTI generated for it. RTTI is only generated for explicitly declared types. That is why the 2nd snippet works. I'm sure this is documented somewhere.

Comment: Consequently, this means that I have to instruct the user developers how to declare their types within the class. Thank you Remy and Peter or the clarification.